# Is it possible to call an object method this way in C++?

Tags: c++, methods

Here's my class definition:

```
class A {
    public:
        void do_lengthy_work() {
        cout << "working." << endl;
        }
};
```

I have an object of type `A`, and I want to call `do_lengthy_work()` on it:

```
A a;
a.do_lengthy_work();
```

Is it also possible to call the same method using some variant of the following?

```
A::do_lengthy_work(a);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can wrap the function with `mem_fun_ref`:

```
mem_fun_ref(&A::do_lengthy_work)(a);
```

This can be very useful for STL algorithms like `for_each`:

```
std::vector<A> vec;
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), mem_fun_ref(&A::do_lengthy_work));
```

If you have an `A *`, you would use `mem_fun`:

```
std::vector<A *> vecp;
std:for_each(vecp.begin(), vecp.end(), mem_fun(&A::do_lengthy_work));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the method is declared to be `static`, meaning it does not belong to a particular instance of the class.

```
class A {
    public:
    static void do_lengthy_work() {
        cout << "working." << endl;
    }
};

A::do_lengthy_work();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this.

```
static void do_lengthy_work(A& a) {
    a.do_lengthy_work();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you wrote it, no you can't do that.  You *could* create a static overload, although I would advise against this:

```
class A {
    public:
        void do_lengthy_work() {
        cout << "working." << endl;
        }

        static void do_lengthy_work(A& a) {
            a.do_lengthy_work();
        }
};
```

However, this can be confusing.  Why do you want to do this?  Why can't you just call `a.do_lengthy_work()`?

Comment: Just curious, because this is something that can be done in Python.